# Custom Lightning Components Failing with the new Summer '17 Release?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, community-builder, lightning-community

I've created a couple of months ago some custom lightning components that would be used for a Community tailoured with the Napilii template. I remember that those components worked fine back then.

After getting back to the project for some new developments and extensions I see that the components show some error in the builder: "Community builder can't display this component because it was passed an invalid value. Ask your Salesforce admin for help."

EDIT after @Keith C's comment: I don't think that is an issue related with the Locker Service introduction in this release, as this components used to work under the activation of the Locker Service Update, previously.

The screenshot for convenience:

[image]

Is there any new interface that I should implement in order to use this components? Or any other guideline that would make this components compatible with the new Spring 17' Release?

Comment: Do you mean Summer '17? The [Locker Service in Summer 17](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.ie/2017/04/locker-service-in-summer-17.html) may be involved in your problem.

Comment: I am not sure about that beacuse I remember that those components worked fine when I tested them with the Locker Service Update activated.

Comment: Have you used ltng: require tag to include slds. If yes remove it and try. It will not impact your view.

Comment: No, I haven't used the ltng:require to include slds in any of those components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I had to run a run all tests for all my apex classes, I noticed that one of my classes was invalid and needed recompilation. I found out that the problem was with that class because it was used by all the apex controllers of my Lightning components. After I validated the class, all my components, continued to work as they should.

So to recap, this kind of error, at least in my case, was not due to the new summer 17' release, but due to invalid dependent apex classes.